# New apk version field

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I want to upload a new version of my app, but the upload failed.

This is the message:

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

```
[ SHA1: 30:36:E4:D2:CE:4F:3A:C9:76:93:EF:BB:67:B0:27:7A:9A:78:57:CC ]
```

and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint
(s):

```
[ SHA1: 03:BD:1A:6C:74:D8:8C:95:D5:67:C1:C4:E2:FA:65:B9:BA:A6:8D:88 ]
```

Comment: Are you using two different certificate keystore to sign your application? where is first one you have signed with and uploaded your application?

Comment: @ChintanRathod I do not remember the certificate keystore.